# Java, Maven: org.json isn't recognized (Class Not Found With Maven)

Tags: java, json, maven

I have a Maven project (in Java) that was going very well. I work in Eclipse Neon.

Now I want to be able to store data in JSON, so after googling, I chose [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java). In the README it says:

> JSON-java releases can be found by searching the Maven repository for groupId "org.json" and artifactId "json".

Thus, my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.github.runningchickendev.ecomarket</groupId>
    <artifactId>EcoMarket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <repositories>
        ...

        <repository>
            <id>org.json</id>
            <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Then, I tried `Run -> Maven Install`, and it seemed to be working. However, when I try to get this jar run (I don't execute it myself, it is loaded as a plugin), it throws a `ClassNotFoundException:org.json.JSONObject`.

I'm using jdk-1.8 if that's of any importance.

Comment: This works for me.  I don't see any version 20160810.           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Well ... You use Maven to _build_ your project, not to _run_ it. So, how do you run it? To make it short: You need to make sure that every needed library is on the classpath, or - more general - the class loader you use finds it.

Comment: *..when I try to get this jar run (I don't execute it myself, it is loaded as a plugin)* what way are you trying to do this?